# simple performance calculation dependent on different factors

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have to decide performance of some exam,

Performance is dependant on few factors:

1. *factor1  :* x1 out of y1 where x1<=y1, e.g. I checked 6 options out of 10, nearer the value of x1 to y1, better the performance.
2. *factor2  :*

   **z1     :    pn**

Years 1 :   p1%

Years 2 :   p2%

Years 3 :   p3%

where p1,p2,p3 can be any number between 0-100. We need to find the mean percentage and better percentage means better performance

3. *factor3 :*

a) q1 out of r1 where q1<=r1, nearer the value of q1 to r1, better the performance.

b) q2 out of r2 where q2<=r2, nearer the value of q2 to r2, better the performance.

c) q3 out of r3 where q3<=r3, nearer the value of q3 to r3, better the performance.

4. factor4 : it is a number m, highest the number better the performance.
5. *factor 5:*  It will can be anything out of 5. nearer to 5 better the performance.

**In final performance calculations, all the factors will contribute in below manner:**
factor1 : 5%
factor2 : 20%
factor3 : 20%
factor4 : 5%
factor5 : 50%

Comment: Can you further explain what your question is? Are you trying to create a grading rubric here?

Comment: Yes, kind of..Question is..Performance in an exam dependant on many factors (not evenly) and each factor has its own way to calculate performance. So, I need to calculate the final performance which I should be able to put in any kind of scale...like 1 to 5 scale or 1 to 10 scale.

Comment: Well why don't you simply scale every factor so that each is 1-100, where 100 is best and 1 is worst. Then you can multiply each factor by the desired scale and sum them to get your final score out of 100.

Comment: How to deal with factor 4 which I can't scale..it can be any number...bigger the number better the performance

Comment: While it might be technically unbounded, there's still probably some upper limit that is reasonable. Or maybe there is the highest score that any student received. Setting that as the upper limit, you can consider anyone else's as a percentage of that limit or maybe a percentage on the log plot of that limit.